# Returning Value as Renderable HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, return, render

I'm don't have a whole ton of experience with JS, and I'm running into what I would assume is a really simple issue, that baffles me nonetheless because I don't understand the syntax.

I've got a snippet that reads thusly:

```
if( typeof item.id !== 'undefined') {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.name
    };
}
```

I would like to change the "label" value so that it has some html added to it. So my thought was to approach like so:

```
if( typeof item.id !== 'undefined') {
    return {
        label: <a href="https://example.com/' + item.seo + '/' + item.id + '"><p>' + item.name + '</p></a>,
        value: item.name
    };
}
```

The issue that I'm running into here is that the HTML is just printing, not being rendered as html. So I end up with a text string that includes all my HTML characters. Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use `[MyElement].innerHTML` = ... or `$([MyElement]).html(...)` (jQuery) the text you enter where you see ... will be rendered as html.

Comment: Like this?          `label: $(this).html('<a href="https://example.com/' + item.seo + '/' + item.id + '"><p>' + item.name + '</p></a>'),`     This returns [object, Object], so I'm thinking I'm getting something a bit wrong here, mainly that "this" is probably supposed to be something different but I'm not trying to reference something on the page, I'm just trying to specify that the return value be interpreted as HTML instead of plain text. Thoughts?

Comment: @user1709061 what is "renderable html"? HTML is plain text, so I don't understand where your problem is

Comment: Sorry, terminology issue I'm sure. Basically what's printing out is paragraph text, containing all my code. So on the public side of the page you can see all the tags and such, instead of those tags actually rendering as what they're supposed to. So, I literally see <a href="https://example.com/' + item.seo + '/' + item.id + '"><p>' + item.name + '</p></a> instead of a link that has the item name.

Comment: @user1709061 have you resolved this issue or are you still trying to figure it out. I think your confusion might be in your understanding of how .innerHTML and/or .html() work

Comment: Yeah, still trying to get it figured. You're completely correct about the confusion :)

Comment: @user1709061 Check out this tutorial on using .innerHTML: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp so if you have created your HTML, you just need to do something like parent.innerHTML(generatedHTML)